# RESTful Web Service won't call from URL

Tags: java, rest, web, service, glassfish

I am making a test `RESTful` service which has the role of returning a result of two numbers forwarded via the `URL`.
I'm currently trying: `http://localhost:8080/XMLWSAssignment/AddService/3/5` to combine 3 + 5. However, I am greeted with a `"404"` error in GlassFish...

Here's the code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;


@Path("/MyRestService")
public class MyRestClass {

    @Path("/AddService/{a}/{b}")
    public class AddService {
        @GET
        public String getMessage(@PathParam("a") Integer a, @PathParam("b") Integer b) {
            Integer res = a + b;
            return res.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have also used a path to access the REST-Function on class level: `@Path("/MyRestService")`

Have you tried adding that in your request as well, so it looks like this:
http://localhost:8080/XMLWSAssignment/MyRestService/AddService/3/5

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to combine the two numbers you should pass the numbers in URL as given below

http://localhost:8080/XMLWSAssignment/AddService/3&5